# Show php code to specific crawler

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I have the following construction:

```
<?php if (is_page_template( 'template.php' )  ) : ?>
 <meta name="fragment" content="!">
<?php endif; ?>
```

in header section of my WP site. I need to show `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`
string inside the php if statement only to a specific search engine bot crawler - **yandex** and hide for others. Hot to do that easilly? My idea is to wrap that meta tag or the whole php statement into some other if statement if that is possible or please give me another solution and thank you.

Comment: use this library https://packagist.org/packages/jaybizzle/crawler-detect, before you ask question, try to solve problem on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [user agents for all Yandex crawlers contain the string "yandex"](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/robot-workings/check-yandex-robots.xml) in some mix of upper and lowercase

To keep your UA check simple and for ease of maintenance I would just convert it to lowercase and check whether it contains "yandex".

```
<?php 
$user_agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (strpos($user_agent, 'yandex') !== FALSE) :  ?>
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Combine this with your own *IF* for page type by using `&&` or by nesting the *IF*'s.

e.g. `if (is_page_template('template.php') && strpos($user_agent, 'yandex') !== FALSE) :  ?>`

**Use of library, and alternative headers for UA:**

a comment suggests using CrawlerDetect however this is designed to detect ANY bot not a specific one. You could  customise it, but if you are not using bot detection elswhere you are just adding maintenance complexity and unnecessary processing for your site.

The UA may sometimes appear elsewhere than HTTP_USER_AGENT e.g. HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA. See [CrawlerDetect's Headers.php](https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect/blob/master/src/Fixtures/Headers.php) .
You may wish to extend your check to these other headers but in my view this is unnecessay (Yandex's UA list does not include Opera Mini and I'm pretty sure Russian Yandex won't be using Vodafone for crawling).

Comment: Much appreciate your help!